# Handling data passed to a result argument of AsyncTask.onPostExecute()

Tags: android, json, xml, http, android-asynctask

I have this private class that is within my main activity, and I am using it pull a JSon object off of my server into my app. The code below works fine and will display the JSon object as a string.

```
   private class HttpAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

            return httpBuild(urls[0]);
        }
        // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Received!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            etResponse.setText(result);
        }
    }
```

what I am trying to do is place change the `onPostExecute()` method so it acts like `webResult = result` where `webResult` is an instance variable of the class `mainActivity` The problem is once I do this when I try to put the below code into the `onCreate()` method after HTTpAsyncTask has been called the app fails to display the object and crashes.

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String mainSite = "http://mysitehere";

    private String webResult;
//    private JSONArray floorsInBuilding, roomsInGender;
//    private JSONObject room;
//    private JSONArray arrayOfFloors;
//    private JSONObject room, arrayOfRooms;

    EditText etResponse;
    TextView tvIsConnected;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // get reference to the views
        etResponse = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etResponse);
        tvIsConnected = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvIsConnected);

        // check if you are connected or not
        if(isConnected()){
            tvIsConnected.setBackgroundColor(0xFF00CC00);
            tvIsConnected.setText("You are conncted");
        }
        else{
            tvIsConnected.setText("You are NOT conncted");
        }

        // call AsynTask to perform network operation on separate thread
        new HttpAsyncTask().execute(this.buildBuildingAddress(8));
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Received!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        etResponse.setText(WebResult);
    }
```

I'm wondering what makes the part of the code that displays the result dependent on the HttpAsyncTask. I'm also wondering how I can get the result of the HttpAsyncTask and store it as a string in the main class.

A good chunk of my code is based of of this example.
http://hmkcode.com/android-parsing-json-data/

I'm sorry If my knowledge of android isn't so great but my experience lies in more in java.

Comment: I don't know the specifics of the crash itself. But this approach won't work because asynctask executes asynchronously (of the main thread), while onCreate() executes in the main thread. So etResponse.setText(WebResult) will be executed before your asynctask with web call finishes. Which means that it will set the textview text value to null.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I went and talked to a fellow student and he said about the same thing! That was exactly the problem. I failed to understand that the program would not wait for the Asynchronous task to complete. So it would be attempting to print a null string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to wait till the task is over so that you can override the result with webResult then you may use the asyncTask method onProgressUpdate which runs on UI thread. You may refer android developer site to know how to use that method.

Comment: Thanks this is the method that I ended up going with. As a bonus I can now implement a progress bar in the gui.

Comment: Yes, that's the place where you can show your users a progress bar. Also you can use onPublishProgress method along with onProgressUpdate method.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is that the asynchronous task runs alongside `onCreate()`. So you have to create some piece of code that waits for the task to complete or you have to manipulate the `result` of the async task in the `onPostExecute()` method